# Problems with Twitter on Android App

Tags: android, twitter, motodev-studio

I'm trying to show one public twitter profile in one WebView of my app, is not necessary to login twitter, in the MotoDev Simulator this works fine, but in the physical device don't work, this: "403 fobiden limite exceed rate" error appears, this is the simple code line that I'm using:

> webView.loadUrl("https://mobile.twitter.com/#!/asambleaecuador");

and works fine into de MotoDev simulator AVD

....can somebody helpme please!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure this out?

I was just wondering why you're trying to use "https://mobile.twitter.com/#!/asambleaecuador" instead of simply using "https://mobile.twitter.com/asambleaecuador".

Anyway, I just wanted to say that there's no "MOTODEV simulator AVD", MOTODEV Studio uses the regular Android SDK emulator, nothing special to it. And the problem you're facing is probably due to differences between the underlying implementation of the AVD browser and the one you have on your physical device - Android devices have a great amount of different browser implementations.